# Power Query: Selecting multiple elements in 'value field settings' to measure a specifc field

Tags: powerquery

I'm trying to create a measure that averages the 29 elements' value `[Overtime/Hours_worked]` into one cell, visualised by the [attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eb4LU.png).

`Cell F32` currently shows `[AverageA Total Overtime/Total Hours_worked]` but I want it to be an average of the 29 rows' values as displayed in `cell H32`, `=AVERAGEA(F3:F31)`.

The elements' figures are based upon underlying data from `Data$`, currently amounting to ~150k rows. When creating a *measure* that's averaging the elements' values from `Column E` `[AvereageA Overtime/Hours_worked]` and showing as a % of the 29 elements' aggregate %, I'm running into the problem of averaging the separate elements' underlying data taken from `Data$`. Worth noting is that `F3:F31` is redundant in this instance, I'm looking for the average of the 29 elements' values in `column E` and not their respective averages shown in `column F`.

Am I right to use *measure* here or is there a better way to approach it? If measures can be used, is there a way to design the measure so that it refers to the Pivot Table's shown data instead of the underlying data taken from `Data$`? For instance by designing the measure to refer to `column E` in the pivot table?

**Side note**
The table needs to remain dynamic since `Data$` is being updated regularly. I'm relatively new to Power Query so I'm not sure if there are other ways to solve this, i.e. through `MDX`, but I doubt I'll be able to sort that out myself.

Any and all help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are computing the individual entries in the `AverageA Total Overtime/Total Hours_worked` (so I left it blank), but to compute the totals and averages for the other columns, you can use the `Table.Group` command in a special way with an empty list for the key (so as to return the entire table for the Aggregation operations).

Given:
[image]

**M Code**
*read the comments in the code to understand the algorithm*
*If your overtime% column is in your original data, you can just delete those code lines that add that column*

```
let
//be sure to change table name in next line to your actual table name
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="wrkTbl"]}[Content],

//set data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Area", type text}, {"Hours_worked", Int64.Type}, {"Overtime", Int64.Type}}),

//Add the percent overtime column
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Overtime/Hours_worked", 
        each [Overtime]/[Hours_worked], Percentage.Type),

//Use Table.Group to compute total/averages for the last row
//Be sure to use the exact same names as used in the original table
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom", {}, { 
        {"Area", each "Totals",type text},
        {"Hours_worked", each List.Sum([Hours_worked]), Int64.Type},
        {"Overtime", each List.Sum([Overtime]), Int64.Type},
        {"Overtime/Hours_worked", each List.Sum([Overtime])/List.Sum([Hours_worked]), Percentage.Type},
        {"AverageA Overtime/Hours_worked", each List.Average([#"Overtime/Hours_worked"]), Percentage.Type} 
        }),

//Append the two tables to add the Totals row
    append= Table.Combine({ #"Added Custom", #"Grouped Rows"})
in
    append
```

results in =>
[image]

Comment: Thanks ron, highly appreciated. I'll update this post later in the week when I get a chance to implement the solution.